# Handle windows authentication pop up on Chrome using AutoIT

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-c#, autoit

I am trying to handle the basic authentication pop up for my Selenium webdriver scripts using AutoIt in Chrome.

I am using following AutoIt script:

```
If WinExists("","Chrome Legacy Window") Then
   Send("username{TAB}")
   Send("password{ENTER}")
   EndIf
```

No action is performed on the chrome authentication pop-up.

Comment: are you compiling the autoIT code into .exe file and then calling the .exe in Java using the Runtime.getRuntime.exec()?

Comment: yes, i am compiling the autoIT code into .exe file and then calling the .exe in C# using Process.Start() method.